# How to dump and save function arguments without embedding all of the container's content?

Tags: python

I am trying to save all function arguments as it is ran, to a container. Container is common for all funcs ran in the script. How to ensure all container's content is NOT saved every time I save function arguments?

Below decorator saves function arguments:

```
import inspect
from datetime import datetime
import time

def func_logger(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        method_args = inspect.signature(method).bind(*args, **kw).arguments

        runtime     = str( datetime.now() )
        name        = method.__name__
        module      = method.__module__
        signature   = runtime + ': ' + '.'.join([module, name])

        ts     = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te     = time.time()

        kw['log'][signature] = {}
        kw['log'][signature]['time'] = round(te - ts, 2)
        kw['log'][signature]['args'] = method_args

        return result
    return wrapper
```

And an example function:

```
@func_logger
def test(a, b=4, c='blah-blah', *args, **kwargs):
    return 4**4**8
```

When I am running the following snippet:

```
log = {}
output = test(1,4,2,4,1,par=1, log=log)
output = test(1,4,2,4,1,par=1, log=log)

log
```

I receive this output:

```
{'2019-05-17 13:48:25.214094: __main__.test': {'time': 0.0,
  'args': OrderedDict([('a', 1),
               ('b', 4),
               ('c', 2),
               ('args', (4, 1)),
               ('kwargs', {'par': 1, 'log': {...}})])},
 '2019-05-17 13:48:25.215092: __main__.test': {'time': 0.0,
  'args': OrderedDict([('a', 1),
               ('b', 4),
               ('c', 2),
               ('args', (4, 1)),
               ('kwargs', {'par': 1, 'log': {...}})])}}
```

I already tried a workaround - a function that removes 'log' entry from the dictionary. However, every next item in this log stores of the log's current content. So when I try this:

```
list( log.items() )[-1][-1]['args']
```

The output is this:

```
OrderedDict([('a', 1),
             ('b', 4),
             ('c', 2),
             ('args', (4, 1)),
             ('kwargs',
              {'par': 1,
               'log': {'2019-05-17 13:45:45.748722: __main__.test': {'time': 0.0,
                 'args': OrderedDict([('a', 1),
                              ('b', 4),
                              ('c', 2),
                              ('args', (4, 1)),
                              ('kwargs', {'par': 1, 'log': {...}})])},
                '2019-05-17 13:45:45.749221: __main__.test': {'time': 0.0,
                 'args': OrderedDict([('a', 1),
                              ('b', 4),
                              ('c', 2),
                              ('args', (4, 1)),
                              ('kwargs', {'par': 1, 'log': {...}})])},
                '2019-05-17 13:45:45.750218: __main__.test': {'time': 0.0,
                 'args': OrderedDict(...)}}})])
```

So essentially, such a workaround won't work because with time, the memory would get clogged quickly.

Is there any way decorator would not save log entry every time I save function arguments? What I would rather like to avoid is to create a new 'log = {}' container every time I want to dump arguments from a new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply store the log parameter if present and remove it from `**kw`:

```
def func_logger(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        try:
            log = kw['log']
            del kw['log']
        except KeyError:
            log = None

        method_args = inspect.signature(method).bind(*args, **kw).arguments

        runtime     = str( datetime.now() )
        name        = method.__name__
        module      = method.__module__
        signature   = runtime + ': ' + '.'.join([module, name])

        ts     = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te     = time.time()

        if log is not None:
            log[signature] = {}
            log[signature]['time'] = round(te - ts, 2)
            log[signature]['args'] = method_args

        return result
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

use global `log` in `func_logger`

```
log = {}
def func_logger(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        # pass
        log[signature] = {...}
        return result
    return wrapper
```

then, use `output = test(1,4,2,4,1,par=1)`

Comment: log entry is still present in the output so @Serge solution is more complete

Comment: well, I misunderstood your question.   : - )